# For loop only showing last value instead of them all | Cryptocurrency

Tags: python, csv, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to make a crypto scanner but I'm stuck on a problem. I made a small csv file with some crypto currencies looking as follows:

```
BTC-USD
ETH-USD
ADA-USD
BNB-USD
```

Now I want to loop through this csv file and put all the values in the function for df. The problem now is that it only inserts the last value of the file and gives the graph of that coin. I tried this as follows:

```
with open('symbols.csv') as f:
    symbols = f.read().splitlines()
    for symbol in symbols:
        df = yf.download(symbol, start='2020-01-01')
```

I feel like it's doing it's job because I get the following output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
```

Now I want to get the 4 graphs from all the coins and not only the last coin in the csv file. Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance!

NOTE: The rest of the code is working and giving the correct values, the only thing missing now is the loop to get outputs from different coins.

My entire code is:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


with open('symbols.csv') as f:
    symbols = f.read().splitlines()
    for symbol in symbols:
        df = yf.download(symbol, start='2020-01-01')

# df = yf.download('ADA-USD', start='2021-01-01')

df['SMA'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).mean()
df['stddev'] = df.Close.rolling(window=20).std()
df['Upper'] = df.SMA + 2* df.stddev
df['Lower'] = df.SMA - 2* df.stddev
df['Buy_Signal'] = np.where(df.Lower > df.Close, True, False)
df['Sell_Signal'] = np.where(df.Upper < df.Close, True, False)

buys = []
sells = []
open_pos = False

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.Lower[i] > df.Close[i]:
        if open_pos == False:
            buys.append(i)
            open_pos = True
    elif df.Upper[i] < df.Close[i]:
        if open_pos:
            sells.append(i)
            open_pos = False

print('zoveel buys:', buys)
print('zoveel sells:', sells)

# print(df.dropna())

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
# plt.scatter(df.index[df.Buy_Signal], df[df.Buy_Signal].Close, marker = '^', color ='g')
# plt.scatter(df.index[df.Sell_Signal], df[df.Sell_Signal].Close, marker = '^', color ='r')
plt.scatter(df.iloc[buys].index, df.iloc[buys].Close, marker = '^', color ='g')
plt.scatter(df.iloc[sells].index, df.iloc[sells].Close, marker = '^', color ='r')

plt.plot(df[['Close', 'SMA', 'Upper', 'Lower']])
plt.fill_between(df.index, df.Upper, df.Lower, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
plt.legend(['Close', 'SMA', 'Upper', 'Lower'])
plt.show()

merged = pd.concat([df.iloc[buys].Close, df.iloc[sells].Close], axis=1)
merged.columns = ['Buys', 'Sells']
print(merged)
# #
totalprofit = merged.shift(-1).Sells - merged.Buys
print(totalprofit)

relprofits = (merged.shift(-1).Sells - merged.Buys) / merged.Buys
print(relprofits.mean())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
df = yf.download(symbol, start='2020-01-01')
```

you are assigning the result of the download to a dataframe. However, each time you create a new dataframe instead of adding to it.

As such, you either need to do everything you want with the `df` within the loop by calling a function on the df, for example `do_something(df)`
Or you could store it in some `dfs = []` with `dfs.append(df)`, then you'd have each dataframe in an array of dataframes.

Comment: Thanks! I put everything in the same for loop and now it works indeed! I tried to make the dfs list and append all the df but that didn't really work out, because I had to change a lot. I'm not that experience with python yet so I might be wrong there. Like I tried changing all the df to dfs but then it's giving all sort of errors.

Comment: You're welcome! Realize that the dataframes, i.e., `df` are from the pandas package. They have a syntax that is quite different at time from standard python. This can make it very confusing at times!